# Products filters for get_posts function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, posts

Making Search functionality for wooCommerce Products and watching how function get_posts( $args = null )  works, I see that setting args like

```
      $args = array(
            's'                   => 'Some content',
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'numberposts' => 999999, // set maximim value
            ...
        );

        $products_list = get_posts( $args );
```

1) Parameter 's' make search in both post_content and post_title fields. If there is a way to search only in 1 of these fields ?

2) I found that setting 'category' parameter to category I need  - it does not work at all.
After some testing I found that commenting 'cat' parameter inside of get_posts functions makes  'category' parameter working.
What this 'cat' parameter is for?

3) In my search I make filter on price, in_stock fields. And to implement this I have to make check for these 2 criteria manually. I mean I had to set parameter

'numberposts' => 999999, // set maximim value as some big number

and in loop to check these parameters and skip them. I can not set these parameters as filter to get_posts function ?

If I could make what I need with get_posts or if there are better tools for this, maybe some wooCommerce functions ?

4) Also I made search by sku by adding in argumants :

```
            'meta_value'                   => '_sku',
```

looks like that this new condition works as AND, but I need this work as OR condition.
If there is a way to make it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The meta query array can take a key of "relation" which defaults to "AND":

```
    $args = array(
        's'                   => 'Some content',
        'post_type'           => 'product',
        'post_status'         => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'numberposts'         => -1,
        'meta_query'          => array(
                'relation'    => 'OR',
                    array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value'   => 'some value',
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => '_sku',
                    'value'   => 'another value',
                    'compare' => '='
                )
        );
    );
```

Alo, `numberposts` can take -1 as a value to return all the posts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that maybe to target both var,simple product

```
$q2 = get_posts(array(
                            'fields' => 'ids',
                            'post_type' => array('product_variation', 'product'),
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                        'key' => '_sku',
                                     'value' => 'valueInput',
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                             )
                    ));
```